# Debug on device with WP 7.8 on Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-8.1

I am a novice developer for the platform Windows Phone. I installed Windovs 8.1, I also have a HTC HD7 on WP 7.8.
Q: I can't install Zune on Windows 8.1. How do I debug applications for the WP7 on device? They work only through the Zune...

P.S. Zune is installed,but crash bug on startup. I read that the program doesn't work in Windows RT. Is that true? There are no solutions?

Comment: What has Windows 8.1 to do with Windows RT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not necessarily need Zune running to connect Visual Studio to your device, it just needs to be installed.

You can also use `WPConnect.exe` which is located in `...\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\WPConnect\x64\WPConnect.exe` to establish a connection.

Further information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/katriend/archive/2010/10/26/quick-tip-using-the-wp-connect-utility-instead-of-zune-client-windows-phone-7.aspx

P.S.: Zune is working on Windows 8.1 for me. I also have a HTC HD7 with WP7.8

Comment: You're welcome. I forgot to mention that you have even have an advantage when using WPConnect. You can use your camera, because Zune isn't accessing your Mediastorage.